# ArcGIS Javascript API - Use array of values for breaks in Class Break renderer instead of a range for a Dynamic Layer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dynamic-layer, rendering

I'm trying to use ClassBreak renderer in ArcGIS API v3.27. I have a dynamic layer with ZIP as one of its fields. I would like to add breaks based on the ZIP value. But the class breaks usually don't follow a format. For example if i have 1 to 100 ZIPs ( just for ease of explanation) ZIP 1,2,5 might be class break 1 where as 3,6,7 might be class break 2 and so on. How do i use these values for class breaks as they don't fall in a particular range.

Below is the code:

```
crFeatureLayer.on("load", function(){

            var renderer = createRenderer();
            var optionsArray = [];
            var drawingOptions = new LayerDrawingOptions();
            drawingOptions.renderer = renderer;
            optionsArray[0] = drawingOptions;
            crFeatureLayer.setLayerDrawingOptions(optionsArray);

        });

var createRenderer = function() {

        var calculateColorValue = function(value) {
            if (value.hasOwnProperty("attributes"))
                var ZipCR = value.attributes.ZipCR;

            ///Some logic to retrieve class breaks will be inserted here
         }

        var renderer = new ClassBreaksRenderer(null, calculateColorValue);
        renderer.setMaxInclusive(true);
        for (var i = 0; i < ntaData.length; i++)
        {
            addNtaClassBreak(renderer, i);  
        }

        return renderer;
    };

     var addNtaClassBreak = function(renderer, index) {
        renderer.addBreak({
            minValue: index,
            maxValue: index+1,
            label: null,
            symbol: new SimpleFillSymbol().setColor(colorsAvailable[index])
        });
    };
```

The value of the ZipCR is always undefined. How to pass the layer info to the function in case of Dynamic layer. If i use the same code for generating the rendered and apply it to a Feature Layer instead of a Dynamic layer it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

The Class Breaks Renderer can accept a function rather than the field name, see the example [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/renderer_class_breaks.html), which uses the custom function called `calculateSquareMiles`.

Below is code to illustrate your case:

```
yourCustomFunction = function(value) {
  if (value.attributes.ZIP == '1,2,5') { 
     return 1;
  }
  else if (value.attributes.ZIP == '3,6,7') { 
     return 2;
  }
};

var renderer = new ClassBreaksRenderer(null, yourCustomFunction);
renderer.addBreak(0, 1, new SimpleFillSymbol().setColor(new Color([56, 168, 0, 0.5])));
renderer.addBreak(1, 2, new SimpleFillSymbol().setColor(new Color([139, 209, 0, 0.5])));
```

Comment: This worked well for a normal feature layer but when i'm trying it with a Dynamic Layer, the value of the 'value' variable in the custom function is undefined

Comment: The issue here i think is that while defining the renderer for a Dynamic Layer, we create and define the renderer and then assign it to particular layer through drawing options unlike for a Feature Layer. Hence its not able to get to the attributes while creating the renderer.